# HTML5/CSS3 friendly Framework for Tablets

Tags: html

I'm trying to find a quick and dirty framework for HTML5 Tablet design to create a UX.  I'm somewhat familiar with JQuery but it feels extremely optimized for phones vs. tablets. Are there any tools, frameworks etc.. that could just help me bang out a couple pages rather quickly.  Even any example pages on good HTML5 specific to tablets would be very helpful.  For some reason I'm restricted from doing this in native Android (even though it's just a simple UX).  This is meant to be viewed on an Android Tablet..

Comment: Try taking a look at something like http://www.getskeleton.com/

Comment: just as a note it seems we're going forward w/ Dojo.  Again I feel it is not optimized for Tablets. I would like to see JQuery build onto a more tablet friendly framework vs what they currently have which feels geared to phones.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [codiqa](http://codiqa.com). It's an online rapid prototyping tool for creating mobile UI's based on [jQuery Mobile Framework](http://jquerymobile.com).